# How to give each img its own name in PHP, from MySQL query

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Below is my PHP code, i'm looking for the way to give each img its own name then i can select in jQuery.

PHP:

```
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($list=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    print"
        <div class=\"content\">$list[content]</div>
        <div class=\"contentpic\">$list[content_pic]</div>
    ";
}

content    : longtext
content_pic     : text
```

1 content_pic column save several img src: `< img src="http://path">< img src="http://path">...`

This is example what i try to do [example site is a normal e-shop](http://www.asos.com/Vans/Vans-Authentic-Plimsolls/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=691064&abi=1&clr=Black&r=2) 
1 content page there're several content img inside, should I continue find the way give each img own name, then select in jQuery use method to move or... some act. 
OR is there any better solution?

Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not possible without some regex or HTML parsing acrobatics. Why do they need a unique id? Can't you simply walk through them in jQuery? That wouldn't require an id.

Comment: Don't try to work with names or ids. There are better ways but I would need to see the served HTML and know the nature of the intended user interaction that will cause a selection to be made.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Thanks for reply, If without tag id or name how to select in jQuery?

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for reply, the link is example what i want to do, i want select 1 img then it can show or any method in jQuery. http://www.asos.com/Vans/Vans-Authentic-Plimsolls/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=691064&abi=1&clr=Black&r=2

Comment: Also don't use mysql_ functions as they're deprecated, especially if you'll be taking in user input.

Comment: @noko I can't understand. 
My question is how to give a name with PHP MySQL output then i can select in jQuery use method to move. 
1 content page there're several img. 
This is example site what i try to do http://www.asos.com/Vans/Vans-Authentic-Plimsolls/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=691064&abi=1&clr=Black&r=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't save whole img tag html code in MySQL, just save path.
Use PHP explode(), and get the index write to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can give each image it's own ID like this:

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   echo "<img id='myImage" . $counter . "' src='" . $row['content_pic'] . "' />";
   $counter++;
}
```

And then just use JQuery to select each image by using their ID's: myImage1, myImage2...

Comment: This isn't going to work. Look at the format `content_pic` is in

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$name="name='img".$counter."'>";
echo str_replace(">",$name,$row['content_pic'];
$counter++;
}
```